# Laravel PHPUnit returns 404 only in first request

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm having this trouble with Laravel 7.

When I create a PHPUnit TestCase, the first request returns 404, but the second is successful.

```
    $res = $this->json('post', '/api/auth/login', [
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password
    ]);

    Log::debug("---------------------");
    Log::debug("Response");
    Log::debug("---------------------");
    Log::debug(json_encode($res));
    Log::debug("---------------------");

    $response2 = $this->json('post', '/api/auth/login', [
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password
    ]);

    Log::debug("---------------------");
    Log::debug("Response2");
    Log::debug("---------------------");
    Log::debug(json_encode($response2));
    Log::debug("---------------------");
```

The output prints

```
"baseResponse":{"headers":{},"original":{"message":"","exception":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"
```

I've been reading all questiosn but nothing works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The second call: Response2 works fine

Answer (score 0):

The error was detected when in class RouteCollection I setted a Log

```
public function match(Request $request)
{

    Log::debug('---------------------');
    Log::debug('The request');
    Log::debug('---------------------');
    Log::debug($request->getMethod());
    Log::debug('---------------------');
    Log::debug($request->fullUrl());
    Log::debug('---------------------');
    $routes = $this->get($request->getMethod());

    // First, we will see if we can find a matching route for this current request
    // method. If we can, great, we can just return it so that it can be called
    // by the consumer. Otherwise we will check for routes with another verb.
    $route = $this->matchAgainstRoutes($routes, $request);

    return $this->handleMatchedRoute($request, $route);
}
```

The result of the first request was:

```
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: The request  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: POST  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1/abcapp/api/auth/login  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------
```

The result of the second was:

```
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: The request  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: POST  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1/api/auth/login  
[2021-10-28 21:55:54] testing.DEBUG: ---------------------
```

My env file was:

```
APP_NAME=ABCApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HelloGuys!
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/abcapp/
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

My env.testing file was:

```
APP_NAME=ABCApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HelloGuys!
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost/abcapp/
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

I solved the error changing the APP_URL from env.testing with this:

```
APP_NAME=ABCApp
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HelloGuys!
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1/
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
```

After that I clear caches. And then works!